# Language review.

Tags: support, languages

I'm Spanish so muy mother tongue is Spanish. I write and speak English quite well. I have to do a kind of project at the university about Lax-Milgram theorem and for that I have to write an abstract in English. I read math in English and I understand quite well but I'm not sure about me writing maths in English. Can I post my abstract for a little review? As many of this site can speak or know writing math in English, I want a little help of advice to improve my text, It's very easy, it's not about the mathematical content it would be about the language content. Can I post that in stackexchange or this site it is not about that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi! Well, this site is more oriented to questions and answers, so maybe it would not be your best option, however you do can send it to individuals like me if you want, also, I'm a mexican citizen, so I may help you with grammar since I understand your issue.

Comment: I don't know anybody on this site, It would be great to send it to you. I haven't do it yet, this is for April or June, so I'll do it. If you won't can no problem tell me. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can have a look at past questions tagged ([tag:translation-request]) to see some past "translation-related" questions and how they were received. However, this is probably not ideal for the main site. It might be a more natural to ask whether somebody is willing to help in some chatroom associated with [this site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=math.stackexchange.com) or some site related to [learning English language](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=ell.stackexchange.com). (Maybe the latter, if it's more about language than about math..?)

Comment: Pablo Ivan, are you still interested on that?

Comment: Hi! Absolutely, I am still interested on working on a translation, yes.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! But how can I talk with you?

Comment: Hmmm... do you have a Facebook account so we can chat on Messenger?

Comment: No me deja contactarte por facebook, el mensaje en cuestión es:

Comment: Hola Pablo Iván, soy el de MathStackexchange, el que pedía ayuda para una traducción. Aquí te doy un enlace con el resumen en cuestión https://mega.nz/#!zkhwBKCK!VQclZ6UePjHMOigHXcvCw6P05IXnSaIhSAJIUG0zQhg, es un archivo .rar con el texto en .tex para que sea fácil hacer modificaciones y en .pdf ya compilado para que te sea más fácil verlo. Es un resumen sobre un trabajo sobre el teorema de Lax-Milgram, un teorema de análisis funcional que tiene diversas aplicaciones en ecuaciones en derivadas parciales.

Comment: Mi inglés por escrito puede ser un poco pobre por lo que me gustaría que me ayudaras a corregir errores y a mejorar todo lo que sea mejorable para que sea un buen resumen. Cualquier duda coméntemelo y muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Puedes enviarme un mail a laskerjpc[@]gmail.com si quieres para poder seguir hablando por privado y a ver si podemos comunicarnos por el facebook.

Comment: ¡Claro que sí! Enseguida comenzaré a leer tu trabajo.